# View Background Image can't wrap content properly, making some margins

Tags: android, android-layout

My background image of view is making some weird margins i don't need. Here is the photo:

[image: hmmm...]

As you can see TextView is highlighted and the View (with blue background image) should wrap around that TextView, but it looks like TextView is making some margins.
Here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white_as_stone">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_user"
    android:id="@+id/view_user"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_margin_to_side"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/view_margin_to_side"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/side_margins"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/side_margins"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/side_margins">
    <!-- margins above have nothing to do with my problem -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="why y doing this?"
        android:id="@+id/txt_user"
        android:textColor="@color/white_as_stone">
        </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my background image:

[image: circle_user.9.png]

I don't have much experience with 9-patch drawables, i tried tweaking scale area, but it doesn't help. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the black lines at the bottom and right of your 9patch image. They define the available content area for the image.

Comment: i thought about it (it was called fill area after all), but apparently you need to press Save when you edit area, and then Refresh in design preview to see changes which I forgot. Anyway, thank you very much for your help